# Prove that P(A-B) = P(A) - P(A and B) using Probability axioms

Tags: probability

I have tried many ways
P(A-B) = P(A and B') 
Then i applied DeMorgan's law and got  P(A and B')' = P(A' or B)
Since A' and B are disjoint set we get 1- P(A and B') = P(A') + P(B)
And then i got an absured result that P(A and B') = P(A) - P(B)
What is wrong here, i think i have done something wrong in applying DeMorgan's law.

Comment: What is $A'$? The complement of $A$?

Comment: You are stating that P(A and B')'=P(A' or B), but what exactly do you mean by P(A and B')'? That is not a familiar notation. A correct conclusion would be 1-P(A and B')=P(A' or B). Further what makes you think that A' and B are disjoint sets? I think that is your essential mistake.

Answer (score 6):

We know that,

$A = (A \cap B) \cup (A\cap B')  $

So $P(A) = P((A \cap B) \cup (A\cap B'))  $

Since $(A \cap B)$ and $(A\cap B')$ are disjoint events and

So,

$P(A\cap B) + P(A\cap B') = P(A)$

Then you have:

$P(A-B) = P(A\cap B') = P(A) - P(A\cap B)$

Comment: @parshyaa If this answer helps you out then you should *accept* it.

Answer (score 1):

$A\cap B$ and $A-B$ are two *disjoint* sets/events and this with $$A=(A\cap B)\cup(A-B)$$

Then the additivity of $P$ allows us to conclude that:$$P(A)=P(A\cap B)+P(A-B)$$or equivalently:$$P(A-B)=P(A)-P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Wow thank you so much, could you point out mistake in my way